# Wired invalid syntax Discord Bot

Tags: python

I started writing an discord bot and it worked several times, I only added the !random command.
And now I get an error. 
This is my code:

```
import discord
import asyncio
import random
import time

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("---------------------")
    print("Eingelogt als")
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print("---------------------")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.lower().startswith("!test"):
        await client.send_message(message.channel, "Test bestanden")

    if message.content.lower().startswith("!münze"):
        choice = random.randint(1,2)
        if choice == 1:
            await client.add_reaction(message, "")
        elif choice == 2:
            await client.add_reaction(message, "")

    if message.content.lower().startswith("!random"):
        await client.send_message(message.channel, random.randint(0,100)



client.run('right token checked multipe times')
```

This is the error:

```
  File "C:/Users/Woodpecker/Desktop/1010/Python/Reddit_Bot/Woodpecker´s secretary.py", line 33
    client.run('token')
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Same as always. Count the punctuation.

Comment: The previous line is missing a right parentheses at the end.

Comment: Did you mean to post your token in the debug log?

Comment: can you give me an exampe?

Comment: @Woodpeckerfpv "the previous line is missing a right parentheses at the end" is very specific.  I'm curious why you want an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`await client.send_message(message.channel, random.randint(0,100)`

You need to add an extra `)`

`await client.send_message(message.channel, random.randint(0,100))`